# (Pythin , MySQL) DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '196.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306' (113)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

Connecting remote mySQL server failed, I did make sure the MySQL is running, that Django can connect successfully, but want to connect python with mySQL failed

- the python code (run in google colab)

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="196.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  user="xxxxx",
  passwd="xxxxxx", 
  database="Unnamed"  # I tried to put "cloud_db" and "Unnamed" is not work
)
                
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webpage")                       
                                         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for row in myresult:
  print(row)
```

- error output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MySQLInterfaceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py in _open_connection(self)
    267         try:
--> 268             self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
    269             self._cmysql.converter_str_fallback = self._converter_str_fallback

MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on '196.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306' (113)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py in _open_connection(self)
    271                 self.converter.str_fallback = self._converter_str_fallback
    272         except MySQLInterfaceError as err:
--> 273             raise get_mysql_exception(
    274                 msg=err.msg, errno=err.errno, sqlstate=err.sqlstate
    275             ) from err

DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '196.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306' (113)
```

**when I connect Django and mySQL the following info is working**, but stock on python to MySQL connection

[image]

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use SQL tool connect first, that if connect success, you could know the `host` , `password`.. is correct, then is coding problem

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  user="root", # defult user name is root
  password="password", 
  database="your_database",  
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password' # In case plugging password is not working
)
                
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM your_kist")                       
                                         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for row in myresult:
  print("row_01 = ", row[0], )
  print("row_02 = ", row[1])
  print("row_03  = ", row[2])
  print("row_04  = ", row[3], "\n")
```